# Remove weird padding/margin on v-image-input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using the external component v-image-input in Vuetify. For some reason, the component creates this extra padding/margin on the right and bottom side. I have been unable to find any attribute that can change this. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some hidden elements in the HTML.

If you go to https://seregpie.github.io/VuetifyImageInput/ and click on 'hide actions' the elements disappear.

Comment: Thanks! Adding "hide-actions" attribute to the v-image-input solved the issue :)